# Google Maps: How to create a custom InfoWindow?

Tags: javascript, html, css, google-maps

The default Google Maps InfoWindow for a map marker is very round. How do I create a custom InfoWindow with square corners?

Comment: I updated my answer with a link to something that looks quite customisable.  You can choose your own radius and other settings.

Comment: [Check out this answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/7628522/881250) for another example of creating a custom InfoBoxes

Answer (score 84):

**EDIT** After some hunting around, this seems to be the best option:

https://github.com/googlemaps/js-info-bubble/blob/gh-pages/examples/example.html

You can see a customised version of this InfoBubble that I used on [Dive Seven, a website for online scuba dive logging](http://diveseven.com/atlas).  It looks like this:

[image]

---

There are some more examples [here](http://googlemaps.github.io/libraries.html).  They definitely don't look as nice as the example in your screenshot, however.

Comment: @TWilly, thanks. The project moved to GitHub. I've updated the URLs.

Comment: Please update your links and demo map as they don't work.

Answer (score 17):

You can modify the whole InfoWindow using jquery alone...

```
var popup = new google.maps.InfoWindow({
    content:'<p id="hook">Hello World!</p>'
});
```

Here the <p> element will act as a hook into the actual InfoWindow. Once the domready fires, the element will become active and accessible using javascript/jquery, like `$('#hook').parent().parent().parent().parent()`.

The below code just sets a 2 pixel border around the InfoWindow.

```
google.maps.event.addListener(popup, 'domready', function() {
    var l = $('#hook').parent().parent().parent().siblings();
    for (var i = 0; i < l.length; i++) {
        if($(l[i]).css('z-index') == 'auto') {
            $(l[i]).css('border-radius', '16px 16px 16px 16px');
            $(l[i]).css('border', '2px solid red');
        }
    }
});
```

You can do anything like setting a new CSS class or just adding a new element.

Play around with the elements to get what you need...

Comment: This is a dirty hack that could stop working anytime!

Comment: hack - sure. genius - absolutely!

Comment: An ID for a element that surely will be repeated in the page, that's not a good practice. ID should be unique in the page.

Comment: @PhilippeLavoie You can add a count to the id each time you create a new infowindow.

Answer (score 8):

I found InfoBox perfect for advanced styling.

> An InfoBox behaves like a **google.maps.InfoWindow**, but it
>   supports several additional properties for advanced styling. An
>   InfoBox can also be used as a map label. An InfoBox also fires the
>   same events as a **google.maps.InfoWindow**.

Include http://code.google.com/p/google-maps-utility-library-v3/source/browse/trunk/infobox/src/infobox.js in your page

Comment: Your links are dead.

Answer (score 5):

Styling the infowindow is fairly straightforward with vanilla javascript. I used some of the info from this thread when writing this. I also took into account the possible problems with earlier versions of ie (although I have not tested it with them).

```
var infowindow = new google.maps.InfoWindow({
  content: '<div id="gm_content">'+contentString+'</div>'
});

google.maps.event.addListener(infowindow,'domready',function(){
  var el = document.getElementById('gm_content').parentNode.parentNode.parentNode;
  el.firstChild.setAttribute('class','closeInfoWindow');
  el.firstChild.setAttribute('title','Close Info Window');
  el = (el.previousElementSibling)?el.previousElementSibling:el.previousSibling;
  el.setAttribute('class','infoWindowContainer');
  for(var i=0; i<11; i++){
    el = (el.previousElementSibling)?el.previousElementSibling:el.previousSibling;
    el.style.display = 'none';
  }
});
```

The code creates the infowindow as usual (no need for plugins, custom overlays or huge code), using a div with an id to hold the content. This gives a hook in the system that we can use to get the correct elements to manipulate with a simple external stylesheet.

There are a couple of extra pieces (that are not strictly needed) which handle things like giving a hook into the div with the close info window image in it.

The final loop hides all the pieces of the pointer arrow. I needed this myself as I wanted to have transparency on the infowindow and the arrow got in the way. Of course, with the hook, changing the code to replace the arrow image with a png of your choice should be fairly simple too.

If you want to change it to jquery (no idea why you would) then that should be fairly simple.

I'm not usually a javascript developer so any thoughts, comments, criticisms welcome :)

Comment: I don't know if you've heard, but there's these new things called "enter" and "space" which actually creates space when you write on a computer. Typically useful when writing things as code so your eyes don't bleed out from trying to read it :)

Answer (score 4):

Below piece of code may help you out.

```
var infowindow = new google.maps.InfoWindow();
 google.maps.event.addListener(marker, 'mouseover', (function(marker) {
            return function() {
                var content = address;
                infowindow.setContent(content);
                infowindow.open(map, marker);
            }
          })(marker));
```

Here is an article < [How to locate multiple addresses on google maps with perfect zoom](http://www.coolcoder.in/2014/03/how-to-locate-multiple-addresses-on.html) > that helped me achieved this. You can refer it for working JS Fiddle link and complete example.

Answer (score 2):

I'm not sure how FWIX.com is doing it specifically, but I'd wager they are using [Custom Overlays](http://code.google.com/apis/maps/documentation/javascript/overlays.html#CustomOverlays).

Comment: Does a Custom OVerlay have all the same properties as a normal google map marker? Meaning, I can still do setIcon, setZIndex, etc with a Custom Overlay **OR** do I have to re-implement all of that functionality?

Comment: No, custom overlays allow only basic functionality of rendering on the map, if you want setIcon, setZindex, etc. you will have to implement them yourself.

Answer (score 2):

You can use code below to remove style default inforwindow. After you can use HTML code for inforwindow:

```
var inforwindow = "<div style="border-radius: 50%"><img src='URL'></div>"; // show inforwindow image circle
marker.addListener('click', function() {
    $('.gm-style-iw').next().css({'height': '0px'}); //remove arrow bottom inforwindow
    $('.gm-style-iw').prev().html(''); //remove style default inforwindows
});
```

Comment: remove style default inforwindows - the best solution across all SO for now

Answer (score 2):

Here is a pure CSS solution based on the current infowindow example on google:

https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/examples/infowindow-simple

```
#map *{
  overflow: visible;
}
#content{
  display: block;
  position: absolute;
  bottom: -8px;
  left: -20px;
  background-color: white;
  z-index: 10001;
}
```

This is a quick solution that will work well for small info windows. Don't forget to up vote if it helps :P

Answer (score 1):

You can even append your own css class on the popup container/canvas or how do you want.
Current google maps 3.7 has popups styled by canvas element which prepends popup div container in code.
So at googlemaps 3.7 You can get into rendering process by popup's domready event like this:

```
var popup = new google.maps.InfoWindow();
google.maps.event.addListener(popup, 'domready', function() {
  if (this.content && this.content.parentNode && this.content.parentNode.parentNode) {
    if (this.content.parentNode.parentNode.previousElementSibling) {
      this.content.parentNode.parentNode.previousElementSibling.className = 'my-custom-popup-container-css-classname';
    }
  }
});
```

element.previousElementSibling is not present at IE8- so if you want to make it work at it, [follow this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/5197873/389755).

[check the latest InfoWindow reference](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/reference#InfoWindow) for events and more..

I found this most clean in some cases.

Answer (score 0):

I think the best answer I've come up with is here:
https://codepen.io/sentrathis96/pen/yJPZGx

I can't take credit for this, I forked this from another codepen user to fix the google maps dependency to actually load

Make note of the call to:

```
InfoWindow() // constructor
```

Answer (score 0):

Nowadays, Google Maps API offer Custom Popups functionality. See https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/examples/overlay-popup