# Modern rectangular InfoWindow on maps.google.com

Tags: google-maps, google-maps-api-3, google-maps-styling

How can I style google maps v3 InfoWindow to achieve the same style as on [maps.google.com](http://maps.google.com/maps?q=test&hl=en&sll=38.959409,-90.703125&sspn=53.567965,87.1875&z=4&iwloc=J)?

Comment: After short investigation using chrome's developer tools it is clear that google is not just styling its rectangular infowindow with different css rules, but it has completely different structure. Just compare those two screenshots:

[maps.google.com](https://img.skitch.com/20110706-c8b5tr6f3a7c5n36q6rr41i2gm.png)

[classic official api](https://img.skitch.com/20110706-p5m63aiyjr7efk8ym34upwsaky.png)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Rectangular `InfoWindows` are now the default style since Maps API 3.7 (current nightly version).

Comment: how do we achieve rounded corners in 3.7

Comment: can you please put in the url

Comment: @refhat - InfoBubble (http://google-maps-utility-library-v3.googlecode.com/svn/trunk/infobubble/examples/example.html)

Answer (score 2):

The API does not provide for robust styling of the InfoWindow objects (or, if it does, it is not documented). You can see what options are available at http://code.google.com/apis/maps/documentation/javascript/reference.html#InfoWindowOptions. As you can see, right now, there's nothing for things like rounded corners vs. not-rounded corners, etc.

So, sorry to say, it would seem like you are stuck messing with stylesheets, at least at the current time.

Answer (score 1):

Actually thats the first time i'm seeing this. Im sure with google's new design update they are sure to update the Api windows. For the meantime I would use:
[Google Maps: How to create a custom InfoWindow?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3860277/google-maps-how-to-create-a-custom-infowindow)

Answer (score 1):

U can go deep in Css then select responsible rectangle for infoWindow and set styles;

```
#map_canvas div div div div div div div:nth-of-type(12) {
-moz-border-radius:5px 5px 5px 5px;
-webkit-border-radius: 5px 5px 5px 5px;
border-radius: 5px 5px 5px 5px; }
```

Answer (score 0):

Use version 3.7+ of the api (they removed the rounded corners after 3.6)