# how do set border radius for google map infowindow

Tags: javascript, ajax, google-maps, google-maps-api-3

I have google map infowindow,i want to set border radius to infowindow.
 so how do it.

and this is my code

```
  var latlng = new google.maps.LatLng(lat,lng);
  var myOptions = {
   zoom : 8, 
   center : latlng,
   mapTypeId : google.maps.MapTypeId.ROADMAP
   }
 var map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById("map_canvass"),
 myOptions);
 var infowindow = new google.maps.InfoWindow();
 infowindow.open(map, marker);
```

Comment: A very similar question was answered already: [Google Maps: How to create a custom InfoWindow?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3860277/google-maps-how-to-create-a-custom-infowindow). It specifically discussed setting rounded corner radius.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you have to create a custom infobox overlay to change anything other than the content, the google maps infoWindow is if I'm not mistaken just a scaled image.

Go custom! Example here:
http://google-maps-utility-library-v3.googlecode.com/svn/trunk/infobubble/examples/example.html

and here:
http://gmaps-samples-v3.googlecode.com/svn/trunk/infowindow_custom/infowindow-custom.html

Answer (score 2):

You can do it also with CSS. For me works this:

```
#map_canvass > div > div > div > div > div:not(:first-child) > div > div:nth-child(12) {
   border-radius: 10px 10px 10px 10px;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

As I don't like counting to 12, I found the draggable attribute could identify it:

jQuery:

```
$(document).find('#map_canvas').find( 'div[draggable="false"]' ).css('border-radius', '5px');
```

CSS:

```
#map_canvas div[draggable="false"] { border-radius: 5px }
```

Answer (score 0):

Yeah, seem the link is dead and old code no longer works. try my script

```
var infoElement = $('.gm-style-iw').prev();
var boxWrapper = infoElement[0].childNodes[1],
    boxContainer = infoElement[0].childNodes[3];

//then set border-radius to wrapper and container via jQuery
$(boxWrapper).css({
    borderRadius: 4
});
$(boxContainer).css({
    border: '2px solid #FFC800', // if you wanna override new border
    borderRadius: 4,
});
```

[preview here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/R30ED.jpg)

Answer (score 0):

The previous answers seems to be outdated, i succeed doing this with the following css :

```
.gm-style > div > div + div + div > div > div + div > div > div > div + div {
    border-radius: 10px 10px 10px 10px !important;
}
```