# google map infowindow height not working

Tags: html, css, google-maps

I'm using google maps javascript API, I want to create a small InfoWindow with 50px height, I user infowindow.SetOptions({height:50}) but it does nothing! how can I set my height?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3860277/google-maps-how-to-create-a-custom-infowindow

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Give an ID/class to your infoWindow element, you can do this by putting your infoWindow's content variable in a `div` like below:

```
var contentString = "<div id='content'>Your content goes here</div>";
```

And then use CSS to adjust the height:

```
#content{
    height: 50px;
}
```