# kml layer infowindow

Tags: google-maps-api-3, kml, infowindow

I'm struggling to find a way to style the infowindows on this map. I've tried suppressing the infowindow by setting suppressInfoWindows: true but that didn't seem to work. Any ideas would be massively appreciated. I've read through a lot of Google docs and a lot of other posts on here and can't find a solution.

```
     <script>

var geocoder;
var map; 
var marker;
var layers = [];

function initialize() {
geocoder = new google.maps.Geocoder ();
var latlng = new google.maps.LatLng (51.505288, -0.191544);
var myOptions = {
  zoom: 15,
  disableDefaultUI: true,
  styles: [
        {
           stylers: [

  ]
},

{
  featureType: "poi.park",
  stylers: [
      { color: "#aecfae" },
    { saturation: 0 },
    { lightness: 0 },
    { visibility: "simplified" }



  ]
  },

  {
  featureType: "landscape",
  stylers: [
      { color: "#ffffff" },
    { saturation: 0 },
    { lightness: 0 },
    { visibility: "simplified" }
  ]
},

{
  featureType: "road.highway",
  elementType: "labels",
  stylers: [
    { color: "transparent" },
    { visibility: "off" },

  ]
},

{
  featureType: "water",
  elementType: "geometry.fill",
  stylers: [
    { color: "#a5bfdd" },
    { visibility: "on" },

  ]
},

{
  featureType: "road",
  elementType: "labels",
  stylers: [
    { color: "transparent" },
    { visibility: "off" },

  ]
},

  {
  featureType: "road",
  elementType: "geometry",
  stylers: [
      { color: "#e0e0e0" },
    { saturation: 0 },
    { lightness: 0 },
    { visibility: "simplified" }
  ]
}],
  center: latlng,
  mapTypeId: google.maps.MapTypeId.ROADMAP
    }
  map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById("map_canvas"),
    myOptions);

  marker = new google.maps.Marker({map:map});

     layers[0] = new google.maps.KmlLayer('http://www.cid-dev.co.uk/vicarage-phase-2/kml/VicarageGate.kml', {preserveViewport: true});

    for (var i = 0; i < layers.length; i++) {
    layers[i].setMap(map);


  }

  layers[1] = new google.maps.KmlLayer('http://www.cid-dev.co.uk/vicarage-phase-2/kml/PrimarySchools-1.kml',
         {preserveViewport: true});
  layers[2] = new google.maps.KmlLayer('http://www.cid-dev.co.uk/vicarage-phase-2/kml/SecondarySchools-1.kml', {preserveViewport: true});
  layers[3] = new google.maps.KmlLayer('http://www.cid-dev.co.uk/vicarage-phase-2/kml/Culture-6.kml', {preserveViewport: true});
  layers[4] = new google.maps.KmlLayer('http://www.cid-dev.co.uk/vicarage-phase-2/kml/Hotels-2.kml', {preserveViewport: false});
   layers[5] = new google.maps.KmlLayer('http://www.cid-dev.co.uk/vicarage-phase-2/kml/Shopping.kml', {preserveViewport: false});
   layers[6] = new google.maps.KmlLayer('http://www.cid-dev.co.uk/vicarage-phase-2/kml/Restaurants.kml', {preserveViewport: false});
  for (var i = 1; i < layers.length; i++) {
    layers[i].setMap(null);


  }
    }
function codeAddress () {
    var address = document.getElementById ("address").value;
    geocoder.geocode ( { 'address': address}, function(results, status)  {
    if (status == google.maps.GeocoderStatus.OK)  {
        map.setCenter(results [0].geometry.location);
        marker.setPosition(results [0].geometry.location);
        map.setZoom(15);
        } 
    else {
        alert("Geocode was not successful for the following reason: " + status);
            }
}); 
}

function toggleLayer(i) {
  if(layers[i].getMap() === null) {
    layers[i].setMap(map);
  }
  else {
    layers[i].setMap(null);
  }






}


  google.maps.event.addDomListener(window, 'load', initialize);






    </script>



    <div id="map_canvas" style="position:absolute; width:100%; height:100%; top:0px; left:0px; right:0px; bottom:0px; z-index:100; background-color:#000;"></div>
```

Comment: How did you use suppressInfoWindows? I don't see it in your posted code.

Comment: It [works for me](http://www.geocodezip.com/v3_simpleMap_SO_infowindow.html).

Comment: Sorry geocodezip, I took it out of this code, I was just using {suppressInfoWindows: true}. The infowindows work when I don't suppress them but I want to suppress them in order to show a styled infowindow instead if this makes sense? Instead of the infowindow provided by Google's API with their styling

Comment: So your question is not "how do I suppress the existing infoWindows", but "how do I add a custom infowindows"?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Google Maps: How to create a custom InfoWindow?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3860277/google-maps-how-to-create-a-custom-infowindow)

Answer (score 0):

Suppress the automatic info window generation, and use the click event to manually handle the data.

Here's an example that is removing the `target="_blank"` attribute from the info window links: http://people.missouristate.edu/chadkillingsworth/mapsexamples/removekmllinktargets.js

Comment: Hi Chad, thanks for all your hard work. I specialise in HTML and PHP and my Jquery/Javascript knowledge is in it's infancy. How would I go about integrating your code into mine to give the desired toggle effect, but display the custom css infowindows? - Kind regards, Rob.

Comment: Same concept, you would just substitute your custom info window code within the 'click' event listener code (instead of my CommonInfoWindow). You might try the InfoBubble class of the Google Maps Utility Library: http://google-maps-utility-library-v3.googlecode.com/svn/trunk/infobubble/

Answer (score 0):

You can try adding a method like this to all your markers.

```
// generalized click handler
function addClickHandler(item, content, position) {
  google.maps.event.addListener(item, 'click', function () {
    infoWindow.close();
    infoWindow.setContent(content);
    infoWindow.setPosition(position);
    infoWindow.open(map);
  });
}
```

When I am styling with KML anything passed through in <[CDATA tag is formatted. So adding  within the cdata is allowed.

Also heres an example from GOOGLE

http://google-maps-utility-library-v3.googlecode.com/svn/trunk/infobubble/examples/example.html